# Dispose doesn't dispose completely

Tags: flutter, dispose

I noticed something strange, quite probably because maybe I don't understand the concept.

I am listening to cloud message from firebase. I have 2 dart files A and B.

A looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
        print(" onLaunch called $msg");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
        print(" onResume called ${(msg)}");
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
        //showNotification(msg);
        print(" onMessage called in Activity A ${(msg)}");//--!!!!!-------!!!!->notice this
      },
    );
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, alert: true, badge: true));
    firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings setting) {
      print('IOS Setting Registered');
    });
    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print("token: "+token);
    });
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings);
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Sample() ));// calling screen B from action of app bar
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice the line where I print in console if a new message is called in "Activity A"..

Now B looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';


class Sample extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SampleState createState() => _SampleState();
}

class _SampleState extends State<Sample> {

  @override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
  }




  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging1 = new FirebaseMessaging();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin1;
  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    firebaseMessaging1.configure(
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
        print(" onLaunch called $msg");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
        print(" onResume called ${(msg)}");
      },
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
        //showNotification(msg);
        print(" onMessage called in Activity B ${(msg)}");//----!!!---!!!!---Notice this
      },
    );
    firebaseMessaging1.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, alert: true, badge: true));
    firebaseMessaging1.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings setting) {
      print('IOS Setting Registered');
    });
    firebaseMessaging1.getToken().then((token) {
      print("token: "+token);
    });
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin1 = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin1.initialize(initSetttings);
    print(firebaseMessaging1.toString());

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

So the aim is simple. When the notification arrives depending on the activity we are in, it should perform different actions.

If in A, print notification arrived in A

If in B, print notification arrived in B

**But the problem is, when I switch back to A from B (B was called from A using Navigator push), it still prints Notification arrived in B**

Either the dispose doesn't dispose completely or I am missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*dispose* doesn't do anything fancy. It is **your** job to handle custom *dispose* behaviors.

More specifically, you have to explicitly clean all the mess you possibly made. In your situation, this translates into unsubscribing to firebase's stream.

This translates into the following:

```
StreamSubscription streamSubscription;
Stream myStream;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  streamSubscription = myStream.listen((foo) {
    print(foo);
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  streamSubscription.cancel();
}
```

You'll have to do the same thing for all listened streams and similar objects (such as `Listenable`)

Comment: I anticipated something like that. Can you be specific to my case?

Comment: I've already shown exactly what you need to do. You're listening to streams but don't unsubscribe to them

Comment: hmmm...will explore more on this. Thanks